# Allow only some files in subdirectories with .gitignore

Tags: gitignore

I have dir structure like this:

```
static
    admin
    ajax_upload
    books
    css
    font
    media
    robots.txt
templates
src
build
lib
```

I want to **ignore** following direcotories:

- lib
- build
- src
- static

I want to **allow** following:

- static/css/bootstrap-styled.css
- static/css/main.css
- static/css/font-*.css
- static/font
- static/media/default.png
- static/robots.txt
- templates

So I use the following .gitignore:

```
# Ignore
/lib
/src
/build
/static/*

# Allow
!/static/css/bootstrap-styled.css
!/static/css/main.css
!/static/css/font-*.css
!/static/font
!/static/media/default.png
!/static/robots.txt
```

But it doesn't work properly. Could you help me - what I do wrong here? TIA!

**Details**

Real project structure is like this:

```
static
    admin
        css
        img
        js
            admin
    ajax_upload
    books
    css
    font
    media
        uploads
            blog
            gallery
        default.png
    robots.txt
templates
src
build
lib
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

So, the .gitignore works for me is the following:

```
# Ignore
lib/
src/
build/
static/**/*

# Allow
!static/css/bootstrap-styled.css
!static/css/main.css
!static/css/font-*.css
!static/font/*
!static/media/default.png
!static/robots.txt
```

Answer (score 10):

Try the following:

```
# Ignore
/lib/
/src/
/build/
/static/

# Allow
!/static/css/bootstrap-styled.css
!/static/css/main.css
!/static/css/font-*.css
!/static/font
!/static/media/default.png
!/static/robots.txt
```

I think that should work.

Comment: after `git add static/` or `git add static` I see `The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
static
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added`

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev just add the `-f` flag and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Despite being an old post, but still relevant today.

After long debugging with above solutions, it still didnt working for me, but I finally got it fixed by simply executing the following command:

- `git add .\[your_filename] -f`

Where the `.` is expected to be your current directory.

*Saved me lot of time on debugging why my `.gitignore`  is not working and what did i miss.*